# Perform 301 redirect of old blog post urls to new post urls on same server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all existing urls to a new slightly simplified url structure, and wish to keep the existing links that have been indexed on google/bing intact.

The current url for posts looks like this **/blog/post/some-random-post-here** the
new post url's are virtually the same but no longer have **/post/** in them. Instead its **/blog/some-random-post-here**

I have created a new htaccess rule for the new urls. So as of now both versions of the url's work. However I wish to keep one copy for SEO reasons. This is on a blog made from scratch (this is not WordPress or other blogging softwares)

Here are the rewrite rules in my htaccess for old and new urls.

```
**OLD URL:** RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/$ index.php?controller=post&action=view&post=$1 [L]

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**NEW URL:** RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?controller=post&action=view&post=$1 [L]
```

What would I need to add to the OLD URL structure in order to make a 301 permanent redirect to the new url structure? Both the OLD and the NEW rewrite rules are still active. But I rather 301 the old rule to the new URL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RedirectMatch directive for this url redirection, it's easy.

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/post/(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1
```

Or Try mod_rewrite To remove query strings

```
 RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^blog/post/(.*)$ http://example.com/blog/$1? [NC,R,L]
```

Empty question mark **?** at the end is important as it will discard the original query string from url.

will 301 redirect

```
http://example.com/blog/post/foo
```

to

```
http://example.com/blog/foo
```

Comment: That works. The only thing is that it passes original unmodified url structure as well. So this is added after the /foo/?controller=post&action=view&post=foo

Comment: Do you want to remove query strings?

Comment: Yes. I rather not have it be passed in the url

Comment: This works, if the url is example.com/blog/post/foo?querystrings then it doesnt let querystings append to the target url, so, whats your issue?

Comment: It doesn't redirect. It's not redirecting from /post/ to just /blog/